Stream LLM tokens as are generated into Vim like via CLI mods or shell-gpt
Command line tools like mods or shell-gpt allow processing text with LLMs.
They can be used in Vim e.g.:
:3,12!mods -rqf 'Format as markdown bullet point list'

or:
:12,21!sgpt --code 'Implement TODOs for this Rust pseudocode'

The question is:
Currently I have to wait until generation is completed and then I see full result.
However if I open in terminal I see how tokens are generated, so I can start reading result as it is being generated.
How to make Vim/nVim so they will be showing output appearing in given part of text file as it is being generated?

Vim's :!-style commands run a process, capture the output, and then dump into the buffer. If you want a streaming-style solution, you'll have to build on the jobs API (:help channel.txt) and use the callbacks available to process lines as they come.
I don't know that I understood why you'd want to do this, though, because I assume the output is somewhat buffered anyway (that is, you're not getting a word or two back on stdout at a time with enough delay between them to matter). I suppose I could be wrong.

When using tools like mods / shell-gpt with big LLMs , generation of text is streamed and may result in many many lines of text that is generated in many seconds... in terminal you see output as soon as it is generated (e.g. using tee  ... | mods 'blablbal' | tee file.txt  ) so you can start reading output as it is slowly token by token generated, and therefore start editing faster once finished.

Other solution that come to my mind , would open window in Vim , showing output as it is generated , and once finished close window and paste into Vim. (bascially idea inspited by tee)

I got some success with https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim , i.e. :AsyncRun for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do echo $i; sleep 1; done  , and :copen , you can keep reading output as it is generated. Also sending range works: 3,5AsyncRun sort hows those lines sorted. However, to make it complete it would: 1. copy output into original range after completion. 2. remove "|| " previx AsyncRun adds to each line 3. close quickfix window one opens with copen...

vim-floatterm also looks promising. Anyway this is a bit of conversations I had about potential projects that could be helpful base: https://chatgpt.com/share/a0f25263-fa85-483f-b007-00b07728f4b8  , AsyncRun and Vim-Floatterm seem most promising bases for Vim9 and neovim compatibility.
